# Hide div on button press

Tags: php, html, api, bootstrap-4

As per image below I want to show the div beneath the reply button.

(Div being the text box and send button)

[image]

My code below works except no matter which reply button you press the text box opens on the first reply button caused by the javascript function hiding MyDiv and each ID being MyDiv. The problem lies that this need to be dynamic as a I dont know ho many messages I will have.

This is not all the code but should be enough to see what is going on.

UPDATED for minimal code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Example</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

</body>
</html>


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzcq7t0e/

Thanks

Ben

### EDIT

Similar to this question but as above I need it to be dynamic.

[Display div and hide another div by button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014148/display-div-and-hide-another-div-by-button-press)

### EDIT 2

I am still struggling with this.. I have been trying to use jquery $(this).parent().hide();

but having no luck. Should I continue with this method or try something else?

Comment: _“and each ID being MyDiv”_ - that’s the problem, IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Yes but how to be dynamic?

Comment: Use a class and delegate to common parent element - if you clicked `[<>]` snippet editor and created a [mcve] we could show you

Comment: Code updated to minimal example

Answer (score 0):

So I worked it out. adding count ID to the ID tag and a class to hide all divs then show the div with the ID requested.

```
<div <?php echo 'id="myDIV ' . $x . '"' ?> class="reply" style="padding-top: 30px;">  

<style>
    .reply{
        display: none;
    }
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
function myFunction(divid) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV " + divid);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.reply').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```